# Reactive values not working on nested tabsetPanel

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to create a shinyApp with a a set of tabsetPanels within tabsetPanels. However, if on one of those embedded tabsetPanels I have a tabPanel that has a reactive value (a radioButton or a checkboxInput, for example), the reactive item doesn't work, and its value in input is NULL. This is causing some of my graphs to not render properly, if they are in a box with a selector. Any idea of why this is happening or what I can do to fix it would be great.

A reprex app (in this case, the checkBoxInput for the y axis is working, but on my actual app it is not.)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(tidyverse)

options(warn=-1)
data(iris)
data(mtcars)






# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- dashboardPage(

  
  dashboardHeader(),
  
  
  dashboardSidebar(
    
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    
    sidebarMenu(id = "menume",
#selectInput("which unit", "Choose a unit", choices = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd")),
 
  selectInput("colorme", "Choose a color", c("red", "yellow", "green", "blue", "black")), 

    #sidebarMenuOutput("colormenu"),
    menuItem("MTCARS", tabName = "mt", icon = icon("user-tie")),
    selectInput("mtvar", "Choose a variable", choices = colnames(mtcars)),
    menuItem("IRIS", icon = icon("envelope-open-text"), tabName = "ir"),
    selectInput("irvar", "Choose a variable", choices = colnames(iris))
    )
  ),
  
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem("mt", uiOutput("mttabs")),
      tabItem("ir", uiOutput("irtabs"))
      )
      
    )
  



)




# ui <- secure_app(ui, enable_admin = TRUE)


# Begin Server ----------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # output$colormenu = renderMenu({
  #   # Remove the req
  #   selectInput("colorme", "Choose a color", c("red", "yellow", "green", "blue", "black"))
  #   
  #        
  #         })
  

  permission_color = reactive({
    if(input$colorme =="green"){
      
      TRUE
    }else{
      
      FALSE
    }
    
    
  })
  
  
  
  output$mttabs = renderUI({
  output$mtcarsplot1=renderPlot({
    
    
    myplot = ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(x = input$mtvar)) + stat_bin(nbins = 10)
    if(input$tenfoldmt == TRUE){myplot = myplot+ylim(c(0,10))}
    
    myplot
  })
  
  output$mtcarsplot2=renderPlot({
    
    
    ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(x = input$mtvar)) + geom_density()
    })
 
    
  output$mtcarstable1=renderTable({
    tabme= head(mtcars, 5)
    tabme

  
  })
  
  
  
  if(permission_color()==TRUE){
  
  
  
  tabsetPanel(id = "mtcarstabsall",
              
            
              tabPanel("Plots",
                       tabsetPanel(id = "mtplotsall",
              tabPanel(id = "mtplots","mtcars plots",value=2,
                       fluidRow(box(title = "Plot1", 
                                    checkboxInput("tenfoldmt", "Y axis lim 10?", value = FALSE),
                                    plotOutput("mtcarsplot1"))
                       )),
              tabPanel(id = "mtplots2","mtcars plots 2",value=3,
                       fluidRow(box(title = "Plot2", plotOutput("mtcarsplot2")))))
  
              ),
              tabPanel("Tables",
                       tabsetPanel(id = "mttables",
              
              tabPanel(id = "mttable","MTcars tables",value=1,
                       fluidRow(box(title = "Table 1",  tableOutput("mtcarstable1")))
              )))
              
              )
 
  } else{
    tabsetPanel(id = "mtcarstabsall",
                
                
                tabPanel("Plots",
                         tabsetPanel(id = "mtplotsall",
                                     tabPanel(id = "mtplots","mtcars plots",value=2,
                                              fluidRow(box(title = "Plot1", 
                                                           checkboxInput("tenfoldmt", "Y axis lim 10?", value = FALSE),
                                                           plotOutput("mtcarsplot1"))
                                              )),
                                     tabPanel(id = "mtplots2","mtcars plots 2",value=3,
                                              fluidRow(box(title = "Plot2", plotOutput("mtcarsplot2")))))
                         
                )
                
    )   
    
    
    
  }
   })
  
  
  
  
  output$irtabs = renderUI({
  
  output$irisplot1=renderPlot({
    myplot = ggplot(iris, aes_string(x = input$irvar)) + stat_bin(nbins = 10)
    
    if(input$tenfoldir == TRUE){myplot = myplot+ylim(c(0,10))}
    
    myplot
    
    
  })
  
  output$irisplot2=renderPlot({
    ggplot(iris, aes_string(x = input$irvar)) + geom_density()
    
    
  })
  
  

  output$iristable1=renderTable({
    tabme = head(iris, 5)
    tabme
  })
  
  
  
  
  
  if(permission_color()==TRUE){
    
  
  tabsetPanel(id = "iristabsall",
              
              tabPanel("Plots",
                       tabsetPanel(id = "irisplotsall",
                    
              tabPanel(id = "irisplots","iris plots",value=5,
                       fluidRow(box(title = "Plot1", 
                                    checkboxInput("tenfoldir", "Y axis lim 10?", value = FALSE),
                                    plotOutput("irisplot1"))
                       )),
              tabPanel(id = "irisplots2","iris plots 2",value=6,
                       fluidRow(box(title = "Plot2", plotOutput("irisplot2"))
                       )))
              
              ),
              tabPanel("Tables",
                       tabsetPanel(id = "iristables",
              tabPanel(id = "irtable","iris tables",value=4,
                       fluidRow(box(title = "Table 1",  tableOutput("iristable1")))
              )))
              
              )
    
    
    
    
  } else{
    tabsetPanel(id = "iristabsall",
                
                tabPanel("Plots",
                         tabsetPanel(id = "irisplotsall",
                                     
                                     tabPanel(id = "irisplots","iris plots",value=5,
                                              fluidRow(box(title = "Plot1", 
                                                           checkboxInput("tenfoldir", "Y axis lim 10?", value = FALSE),
                                                           plotOutput("irisplot1"))
                                              )),
                                     tabPanel(id = "irisplots2","iris plots 2",value=6,
                                              fluidRow(box(title = "Plot2", plotOutput("irisplot2"))
                                              )))
                         
                ))    
    
    
    
  }
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: It appears that you may be reusing IDs across tabs.  Both Input IDs and output IDs need to be unique.

Comment: You also have render-functions inside render-functions. It's hard to tell what effect that might have but it is neither necessary nor recommended.

Comment: @Jan ahh I took those graphs out from the renderUI and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Have you solved the duplicate ids, too?

Comment: Yes I have, and it's still not working

Comment: You can update your question without duplicate IDs.

Comment: Without reading your code (which is not really minimal TBH), could it be that one of the `inputs` sits on a tab which is not shown? If this is the case, `shiny` does not render the `uiOutput` when it is hidden. If it is not rendered, the inputs sitting on those do not exist. Have a look at `? outputOptions` to make the `uiOutput`  render even if sitting on ahidden tba.